# Groovy Powershell and AWS CLI dynamo DB

Tags: powershell, groovy, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, ready-api

I've been recently given the task of connecting to dynamo DB via SOAP UI in order to assert that my companies APIs are creating the correct content. After hitting a number of brick walls attempting to access Dynamo DB data, we've settled on connecting via a groovy script using windows powershell to utilize AWS CLI and it's authorization provided by Amazon.

I have gone through and configured the AWS CLI, and am able to run commands as expected via power shell, for example:

```
    $ aws dynamodb scan --table-name Accounts
    $ aws dynamodb get-item --table-name Accounts --key '{\"id\":{\"S\":\"3b7e2c4a-f672-4a12-b2bc-7313b60b0a9a\"}}'
```

When switching over to groovy scripts in SOAP UI, the first query works as expected, but the second issue throws the error: "Error parsing parameter '--key': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Here is a snippet of the code of cobbled together from various internet sources that I've been using to run the powershell command:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    //Get details and Build the command
    String powerShellCommand = context.expand( '${#TestCase#PowerShellCommand}' )
    String command = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile  -Command \"${powerShellCommand}\""

    // Executing the command
    Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Getting the results
    powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
    String line;
    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Run query
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
            String jsonString = "";
                while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                        jsonString = jsonString.concat(line);
                }
            stdout.close();
    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Error stuff:
            BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
                    while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
                            log.info(line);
                    }
            stderr.close();
    //-----------------------------------------------
    log.info(jsonString);
```

I belive it may have somthing to do witht he placment of quotes and exscapes but as yet have not found the corret combination, i belive this to be my current input into powershell:

```
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile  -Command "aws dynamodb get-item --table-name Platform.Accounts --key '{\"id\":{\"S\":\"3b7e2c4a-f672-4a12-b2bc-7313b60b0a9a\"}}'"
```

I have even tried a modified version of the code above where i would post in just the AWS command but this just returns a diffrent error: Error parsing parameter '--key': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:

The reason this has stumped me is because this command works as expected when going directly to windows powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to escape the backslash `\` and / or the double quotes `"` with the backtick `.

Or simply to replace the `\` char by the backtick ` char because in powershell escape char is backtick and not backslash...